# the meaning of the sentence "find herself less than average in height"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The tallest girl in her class may stop growing at fifteen
>   and **find herself less than average in height.**
>   Please suggest the sense of the sentence
>   **find herself less than average in height.**

My different opinions about the meaning of this sentence are:

> 1.The tallest girl see that she was not tall any more.
>
> 2.The tallest girl see that she was not tallest in her class as usual.

Comment: to find him|herself + {complement}  = to discover that he|she is + {complement}

Answer (score 1):

You're mostly correct.

However, to be more precise, if she is "less than average," she would be below average--in the bottom 50% height-wise. In other words, once she stops growing, she may find herself among the shorter students in the class.

> adverb, 
>   1. to a smaller extent, amount, or degree: less exact.
>   2. most certainly not (often preceded by much or still):
>   *He could barely pay for his own lodging, much less for that of his friend.*
>   3. in any way different; other:
>   *He is nothing less than a thief.*
>
> adjective, 
>   4. smaller in size, amount, degree, etc.; not so large, great, or much: less money; less speed.
>   5. lower in consideration, rank, or importance:
>   *no less a person than the manager*
>   6. fewer:
>   *less than a dozen*
>
> noun
>   7. a smaller amount or quantity:
>   *Hundreds of soldiers arrived, but less of them remained.*
>   8. something inferior or not as important:
>   *He was tortured for less.*
>
> preposition
>   9. minus; without:
>   *a year less two days; six dollars less tax.*
>
> Idioms
>   10. less than, by far short of being; not in the least; hardly at all:
>   *The job is less than perfect.*